# Extend view and use onLongclick

Tags: android, view

I have extended the android View class, and now I want to define a method in the view that launches when the view is longClicked.

I already have actions for the motionevents using `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. This method doesn't allow for long clicks to take action upon.

I want to do it in the extended View class itself. I'm aware that I can add an OnLongClickListener to the view in the activity, but I'd like to know if there's a way to implement this in the View itself.

```
public class ArchitectureView extends GraphView implements OnLongClickListener {

public ArchitectureView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Log.e("I've been", "longclicked");
    return false;
}

}
```

GraphView is extended from View and also overrides onTouchEvent and calles super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post your onTouchEvent() Method?

I think you'll have to implement the parameters for the longpress as logic inside your that touch event callback.

In order to do so you'd have to test for the "pattern" of a longpress

something like if(ACTION_UP_TIME < (ACTION_DOWN_TIME + someMillis))

EDIT: Upon thinking about it more, couldn't you just implement OnLongClickListener on your view object, then override the onLongClick() Callback?

Like this:

```
public class TestView extends View implements OnLongClickListener{

public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    //I am not certain if you'd need the next line or not.
    this.setOnLongClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v){
    //do things

    return false;

}

}
```

Comment: I've tought about measuring the time, but as android has a built in onLongClickListener I tought it was possible to achieve it easily with it. I've added my onTouchEvent() method, deleted unrelevant code, but I don't think it will help anything.

Comment: I've tried your method, but when I long click on the view nothing happens. There's only one thing I can think of that could prevent it from triggering and that's the overridden onTouchEvent which is in the start post.

Comment: Yeah, the onTouchEvent will have to return false by default, you can return true from some of your case chunks though if you like.

Comment: I always have to do some things on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and when I return false in the DOWN case, my actions aren't registered anymore after a few times.

Comment: It works the way you mean it, I'll find something to fix it for my situation specifically. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

In your view, you may make use of the `GestureDetector` and `OnGestureListener` to achieve this. Formally, you should implements `OnGestureListener` for your View class and define `GestureDetector` within your class.

```
public class YourView extends View implements OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector detector;

    public YourView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        detector = new GestureDetector(context, this); // "this" refers to the OnGestureListener
    }
    // Override onTouchEvent to get the Touch event for the gesture detector.
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        boolean handled = detector.onTouchEvent(e);
        if (handled) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
    // Some override methods from the OnGestureListener interface
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // Your implementation here
    }
    // Other override methods, for example, onScroll() etc.
}
```

Comment: What is exactly happening in your overridden onTouchEvent() method? Why are you returning a boolean if true while the return type is void?

Comment: Sorry, it's typo mistake. In onTouchEvent(), the **GestureDetector** is getting the MotionEvent and fire the corresponding response to the callback defined in **OnGestureListener**. The boolean return in OnTouchEvent indicates if the event is handled or not.